# Cron job and EasyPHP

Tags: php, cygwin, cron, easyphp

I'm using EasyPHP (my OS = Windows XP) and I've written a little php script that should update my database every hour while server is up.

I could include the script into the index.php but then it would only be executed when there is activity on the site.

How can I configure **EasyPHP** or **Cygwin** to execute my cron job ?

thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If its possible to have cron under cygwin then that would be one way.

Another popular way under ms windows is using the scheduler:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569